# Finding local clients from international sites?

Tags: remote

### Any tip for finding jobposts from local clients located in my area/country from sites such as Upwork etc?

(I am looking for quick short projects, not necessarily paying well, and I would think such gigs are often advertised on such sites)

I can google Upwork with country name, but I don't find it efficient.

Comment: You want to filter on your country, Upwork offers exactly that functionality. How is that not efficient?

Comment: I see now you can do that with the Internal search (I was trying with Google).  More precisely the country of client is listed and comes up in a keyword search, nothing more precise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to hire local freelancers in UpWork you have to make a filtered search. When you login to your UpWork client profile, I assume you do have one to hire freelancers, at the top of the dashboard you will notice '**Find Freelancer**' option where you can search for freelancers.

Search for your desired job to be done for example, 'logo design'. Then you'll get a new page with some filtering options. Click on '**Advanced Filters**' option that reveals other filtering options like ***location***, ***hourly rate*** etc.

Customize the filtering options as you desire and click '**Update Filters**'. If everything is okay, you will find your desired freelancers.

[image: UpWork 'Advanced Filtering' option to find Freelancers]

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

I have found craigslist.org useful.  You can save your searches in different countries.